# How to serialize the texture and mesh of a SCNScene in ARKit

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I was reading this example code provided in the Apple docs (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/content_anchors/tracking_and_visualizing_faces) and wanted to try to save one of these ARKit face scenes and look at the 3d model.

I used `VideoTexturedFace` as an example, and added the following to the render method to save the scene to the app's Documents folder after 5 seconds:

```
class VideoTexturedFace: NSObject, ARSCNViewDelegate {
    // ...
    
    var start = Date()
    var tookPicture = false
    
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard let faceGeometry = node.geometry as? ARSCNFaceGeometry,
            let faceAnchor = anchor as? ARFaceAnchor
            else { return }
        
        faceGeometry.update(from: faceAnchor.geometry)
        
        if Date() > start.addingTimeInterval(5) && !tookPicture {
            saveSceneFromView(renderer.scene!, "renderer.usdz")
            tookPicture = true
        }
    }

}

func saveSceneFromView(_ scene: SCNScene, _ urlString: String) {
    let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
    let fileURL = paths[0].appendingPathComponent(urlString)
    print(fileURL)
    let wrote = scene.write(to: fileURL, delegate: nil)
    print(wrote)
```

Unfortunately, when I open the file, my face is not mapped onto the mesh as I expected. The mesh is accurate, but completely blank:

[image]

I'm a beginner so I have no idea if I'm (1) saving the wrong object or (2) saving the object incorrectly or (3) viewing the saved object incorrectly.
Would appreciate some guidance!